# how save checkbox checked into database?

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-sqlite

i need to save checkbox checked into `sqlite database` because if i check a `checkbox` and click on other `tab` and after i click on previous tab, checkbox before checked now is not checked....
I HOPE IN YOU!
THANKS IN ADVANCE!
THIS IS MY CODE:

ADAPTER:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

{

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    public boolean Checked;

    public  PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {

        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public  class PlanetHolder  {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public TextView valuta;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        //public String quantità;
        public boolean checked;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        Checked= settings.getBoolean("Material", false);
        if(Checked) {
           // System.out.println(Checked);
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            System.out.println(Checked);
        }


        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;


        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    settings.edit().putBoolean("Material", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                    System.out.println("presa");
                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                    settings.edit().putBoolean("Material", finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                }

            }
        });


        finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());


            }
        });


        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.valuta.setText(""+p.getValuta());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

        return row;
    }

    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.selected)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }

}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        /*mSharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean mIsChecked = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("zao", false);
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(mIsChecked);*/


    /*  SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean Checked = settings.getBoolean("Material", false);
        //holder.chkBox.setChecked(Checked);
        if (Checked == true){ //false is default value
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true); //it was checked
        } else{
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
        }*/
        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showResult(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();


    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4, "€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                    p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };

        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
        //plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//*
        }*/

    }


    public void showResult(View v) {
        String  result2 = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount2=0;

        String a="";
        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()){

            if (b.selected){

                result2 += "\n" + b.name+" "+b.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount2+=b.distance * quantitaInt;
                //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
    /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.selected){

                result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }*/
      //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
        bun2.putString("scelta", result);
        TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
        transaction2.commit();


        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putString("totale", a);
        TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
        fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
        transaction.commit();
*/













    }



}
```

Comment: you mean sqlite database?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: i tried to use shared preferences...but it doesn't work....i don't know why...

Comment: one thing is that if there is a checkbox in each view, you are saving it with a single "Material" key so there is no way you can retrieve it

Comment: so, how i must write my code?

Comment: I'll post a brief answer down for you

Answer (score 0):

You want to use sqlite just for saving check or you are already using a sqlite database ?

First of all to show the correct checked item when you go back to the check page, you need to store it temporarily in an ArrayList.
You can also use a HashMap for this.

```
HashMap<Integer,boolean> checkMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now when a check is made, just add that value to the map, like this

```
checkmap.put(position,true) or checkmap.put(position,false)// if unchecked.
```

You can have this checkmap as static in your MainActivity and when you go back to the check page, just check the hashmap values and if true check the item again in your adapter.

```
if(checkMap.get(position)){ 
    // check the check box
} else { 
    // else uncheck the box 
}
```

Now this way you will always have the checked and unchecked values in the hashmap.
Now you have to just loop through all the values and store them in the sqlite.
For sqlite you can use the following library : http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

Comment: ok, but if you see my code i tried to use shared preferences....can you say me how use shared preferences in my code? because now shared preferences doesn't work

Comment: In your listview, if you have checkbox in each row, then you cannot use sharedpreferences to make it work correctly. You got to use a hashmap.
What happens when a listview is scrolled, all the rows are refreshed, so your check box will again uncheck no matter if you have saved it in sharedpref or not.
If you really want to use sharedpreference (which is not the correct way in your case), you need to save it like this
    settings.edit().putBoolean(position, finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit()

Only by using position you can get back the value of check on that position.

Comment: Then while retrieving you have to do like this :

  Checked= settings.getBoolean(position, false);
        if(Checked) {
           // System.out.println(Checked);
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            System.out.println(Checked);
        }

Comment: i print position and if i check first checkbox position is "0" and it is ok...when i change tab and comeback to previous tab in consolle i have "0","1","2","3","4" and checkbox before checked now is not checked

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve what you are doing with shared preferences but you need to do the mapping of `key` and `value` correctly. I assume `planetName` is unique here. So if `planetName` is unique then `"Material_"+planetName` will be unique which you can use to save and retrieve data from shared preferences:

Change:

```
Checked= settings.getBoolean("Material", false);
```

To:

```
Checked= settings.getBoolean("Material_"+holder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);
```

and also modify your click listener to look like this:

```
holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    settings.edit().putBoolean("Material_"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                    System.out.println("presa");
                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                    settings.edit().putBoolean("Material_"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: @markella it is hard to debug from here but you can do it from your side to see which part gives you a problem. put Log.v() in couple of areas in getView to see what goes wrong

Comment: i print position and if i check first checkbox position is "0" and it is ok...when i change tab and comeback to previous tab in consolle i have "0","1","2","3","4" and checkbox before checked now is not checked

Comment: actually I meant print the values from shared preferences to see if they are stored ok or not